# How possible vector operations on a matrix that does not fit memory

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata

How is it possible to make calculations on a matrix with size 6GB and RAM is 4GB? What techniques are used in this case? Is there any open source solution or tool using files during vector operations?

Comment: What tools are you intending to use for your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the famous [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) is an open source computing platform, which can be used for operations on pretty big matrices (and not only for that).

For examples, please read [this](http://importantfish.com/one-step-matrix-multiplication-with-hadoop/) page.